# Updating folders and folder contents with Tridion WebDAV

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm facing a problem, and don't know if anybody has solved this issue.
I'm using Tridion webdav (Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1) to insert structured content (folders + binary files) into a publication.
All goes well when the folder doesn't exist, but if the folder exist, then an error appear:

> You do not have permission to access this Web Folder location

Watching the log files, the problem is that Tridion tries to create a new folder when I drag & drop an existing folder, and rename to the folder title, giving an error:

> Name must be unique for items of type: Folder/Virtual Folder within this Folder and its BluePrint context.

I tried using Events to avoid saving the folder when it exists (throwing an exception in the initiated phase), but the permission error appears when updating the content inside the folder.

Has anyone tried to do something alike?
Has anyone any sugestion I can try?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could it be that a folder with that same name already exists in the same blueprint hierarchy?

Comment: Probably I didn't explain it well. The folder exists and what I'm trying to do is update the contents o a folder (subfolders included), dragging & dropping one folder. But Tridion tries to create the folders allways, rising the errors; it seems there is no "Folder update".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Tridion as you are using Windows Explorer to access WebDAV, so if anything it's the Explorer who is to blame for sending wrong requests, but if you will take a look at WebDAV sprcification here: http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html, you can see all the possible calls under chapter 9.

Tridion Folders are treated as collections, so there's a `MKCOL` call to create a folder, but if you will check `9.7.2 PUT for Collections`, you will see:

> 9.7.2 PUT for Collections
>
> This specification does not define the behavior of the PUT method for existing collections. A PUT > request to an existing collection MAY be treated as an error (405 Method Not Allowed).
>
> The MKCOL method is defined to create collections.

So there's no way to update existing folders, it's `create` and `upload contents`, indeed.

You can also check this article if you are interested in WebDAV protocol: http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2011/10/heres-c-webdav-client-that-works-with.html

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with another webdav client (WebDrive), and all works well. When I drag & drop a folder, and it exists, then the usual question of replacing or not the contents of the folder is popped up.